# Why wont VS Code track variable types for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to create a discord bot using JS. I create a .js file for each command I intend to implement and there is a check in the 'main' script that will make calls to the other command scripts. I am going to use pictures to show what I mean when I say that VS code wont tell me the variable type for parameters nor will it tell me any info regarding a method call. Intellisense also seems to not work well in these command .js scripts.

Background Info: I have a lot more experience programming in Java. JS seems to be confusing for me for whatever reason, but I want to learn and understand it better.

I am not going to show all the code, only what is needed for my example.

The main.js script:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client();

const prefix = "++";
const fs = require('fs');
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('.src/commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`.src/commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
client.on('message', (message) => {
    if(message.author.bot) return; 

    console.log(`[${message.author.tag}]: ${message.content}`);

    
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/); 
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase(); 


    if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);

});
```

The ping.js script:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'This is a ping command.',
    
    execute(message, args){
        message.channel.send('Pong!');
    }
}
```

Images:
It just says any, I assume any variable type, I think... But this just seems messy and hard to follow.

main.js
https://gyazo.com/86f7118513df791743def98bcf052f06

ping.js
https://gyazo.com/06bb2e47a3fd39d2e4445591d8537131

Comment: I think this may be because the typings of the *external lib* you're using may not exist, or may not be recognized by VSCode - so it says `any` when it can't automatically figure out what the type is meant to be. If you wrote in TS and installed the required types it would probably figure it out. (TS is excellent on larger projects anyway, and it's very similar to JS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord.js `send()` returns a `Promise<(Message)>` or `Promise<(Array<Message>)>` ([discord.js docs for channel.send()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send)). Promises are great for sequential tasks in any API but don't seem to be a data type recognized by your environment. If VSCode and IntelliJ (as well as many other IDE's) don't recognize the data type of your method's return value or if it isn't predefined (as it more commonly is in Java compared to JS functions or methods), they will highlight the method's return value as `any`.